# Can an electron which is a bound in an atom absorb more than one photon at the same time?

Tags: photons, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

Can an electron which is a bound in an atom absorb more than one photon at the same time ? In specific during photo-electric emission can an electron take in more than one photon if one photon doesn't give it the energy required to drift away from the atom

Comment: One should keep in mind that it is the system "electron+nucleus " that absorbs the photon(s).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is actually often used in a spectroscopic technique called REMPI -- see the image on this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance-enhanced_multiphoton_ionization

There are some important physics techniques that rely on interaction with two photons -- two photon spectroscopy (http://cua.mit.edu/8.421_S06/Chapter9.pdf).

Some other techniques, like Raman spectroscopy, involve interaction with two photons (but one absorbed, one emitted).

Comment: And multi-photon ionisation can occur where such a number of photons is absorbed from an intense laser source that enough energy is available for removal of the electron from the remaining ion, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoionization#Multi-photon_ionization